# Why there define the type in the queen?

Tags: sml

The code form 《ml for the working programmer》 chapter7.1:

```
structure Queue1 =
struct
  type 'a t = 'a list
  exception E 

  val empty = []

  fun enq(q, x) = q @ [x]

  fun null(x::q) = false
    | null _ = true

  fun hd(x::q) = x
    | hd [] = raise E 

  fun deq(x::q) = q 
    | deq [] = raise E
end
```

the code above is exact to the book(omit ;).I and the code to test:

```
val a = Queue1.enq(Queue1.empty, 1)
val b = Queue1.enq(a, 2)
val c = Queue1.enq(b, 3)

fun main() = map PolyML.print c
```

and it works fine.

if I omit the type define line:

```
(* type 'a t = 'a list *)
```

it works fine too!

so why to write the type define? It seems only need a null list [] as the init list. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continue reading your book. Chapter 7 is entitled "Abstract Types and Functors" and this should be a clue as to the reason for this `type t` notation you're seeing.

A very brief primer: functions map one value to another value. Functors do the same thing for modules.

Imagine we want to "build" a `BinaryTree` module that can store values of a particular type. We need to know the type, but also how to compare two values of that type. We can create a signature that reflects that data.

```
datatype cmp = Eq | Lt | Gt

signature TREE_VAL_TYPE =
sig
  type t
  val compare : (t * t) -> cmp
end
```

Then our `BinaryTree` functor:

```
functor BinaryTree (S : TREE_VAL_TYPE) =
struct
  datatype tree = Empty | Node of S.t * tree * tree

  fun insert(existingTree, value) =
    (* Use S.compare to insert the value into a tree *)
end
```

And now when I want to create a tree that holds ints:

```
structure IntModule =
struct
  type t = int

  fun compare(a, b) =
    if a = b then Eq
    else if a < b then Lt
    else Gt
end

structure IntTree = BinaryTree(IntModule)
```

And now adding a value into such a tree might look like:

```
IntTree.insert(IntTree.Empty, 42)
```